# .NET Core project throwing error after installing VS 2017 alongside VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I was working with VS 2015 Professional with update 3. I have an asp .net core project. It was running fine. Then I installed VS 2017. Then I tried to build by original .net core project in VS 2015. It gives following error:

" Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4019 The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.1\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk."

So unistalled VS 2017 and all VS 2015 and resinstalled VS 2015. But still I am getting the above error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with both versions installed you must put a global.json file in the root folder of the vs2015 solution to tell it which sdk to use:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177"
  }
}
```

Comment: Will having the `global.json` file in the solution folder affect others who may be building with only VS2015 installed?

Comment: Will this be the only entry in global.json file?